# why alternatives in function definition in ocaml gives different results?

Tags: ocaml

ocaml 4.01.0+ocp1 on windows 10

New to ocaml, I came across an interesting behavior in the toploop:

```
 let rec fibo n = function
    0 -> 1
  | 1 -> 1
  | _ -> fibo (n - 1) + fibo (n - 2);;
```

throws:

> Error: This expression has type int -> int
>          but an expression was expected of type int

while,

```
 let rec fibo n = 
  match n with
    0 -> 1
  | 1 -> 1
  | _ -> fibo (n - 1) + fibo (n - 2);;
```

works fine:

> fibo 12;;
>
> - : int = 233

Should not these declarations be equivalent, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i got wrong in the first definition. It should read:

```
let rec fibo = function
    0 -> 1
  | 1 -> 1
  | n -> fibo (n - 1) + fibo (n - 2);;
```

which works fine too:

> fibo 12;;
>
> - : int = 233

Answer (score 2):

I'll elaborate a bit on your (perfectly fine) self-answer for future readers.

In OCaml, the `function` keyword adds an anonymous parameter to the function that is used in the pattern-matching. In other words, your first attempt

```ml
let rec fibo n = function
  | 0 -> 1
  | 1 -> 1
  | _ -> fibo (n - 1) + fibo (n - 2);;
```

is equivalent to

```ml
let rec fibo n m =
  match m with
  | 0 -> 1
  | 1 -> 1
  | _ -> fibo (n - 1) + fibo (n - 2);;
```

which does not checkout type-wise.

You can read more about the `function` keyword in [Real World OCaml](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/variables-and-functions.html#scrollNav-2-5).